# Model-Views-Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

Yes, I'm a noob at Xcode. right now I'm working my way through the Big Nerd Ranch IOS programming book, and I just need a little clarification on the Model-View-Controller bit.

Model class is called 'CellData', an NSObject 
View class  'CellView', a UIView 
Controller class is called 'CellAppDelegate', a UIResponder.

The DrawRect method does a lot of drawing, with colors based upon the data from the CellData Class. Everything so far *seems* tells me that I should not call a 'CellData' method from my 'CellView' class. Normally yeah when your just using UIButtons with TestFields, yeah, makes perfect sense.

In this case, I have up to pass a value from 'CellData' to 'CellView' up to 6000 times to refresh a View. Does it still make sense to keep on calling back and forth between using the CellAppDelegate (seems like a lot more work for the computer), or am I really 'allowed' to retrieve a value from CellData?

Comment: Personally I find the Modal View Controller paradigm only partially useful. I use it in the apps structure in general, but if I see a better or more efficient way to communicate within the app, I'll break out of the MVC paradigm. So my advise, if you see a better way to do something, do it.

Comment: @mark, for God sake, it is really fortunately this is you personal opinion only! from that day when you understand the point of the `MVC` you will never want to find another way. however... I know, when someone does not make documentation for the application, no matter which pattern is used. the final result will be chaos in every case when you make a bit more difficult application than the _Hello World!_.

Comment: @holex, I feel what your saying, but just because you break from MVC, doesn't mean your code can't still be easily readable, and thus with a bit of study, easily extendable/mutable.

Comment: @holex _you will never want to find another way_ has been said at some point about every architecture pattern. Every problem has some unique aspect and sometimes MVC isn't the right approach. And I actually think Apple have tied the V and the C too tightly together in iOS anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You've answered your question yourself really. No, 6000 calls per render isn't the right thing to do, especially on a table view cell which will be redrawn pretty frequently.

Personally, I see the controller's job as asking for data objects from the model layer (where business logic etc happens) and passing them into views. So, in your case, I would just pass the data object into your cell. (I would have it as a property on your cell with a setter that also called `[self setNeedsDisplay];` to trigger a redraw)

That being said, I also tend to favour the model layer giving out immutable data objects so the controller / view can't do anything wrong with them :) With this approach, if the controller wanted to edit the data object it would have to call a method in the model layer to do so.

Though, of course, this is just my personal opinion and choice of architecture. And obviously for existing UI objects (i.e. a UILabel etc) I can't pass in the data object, I have to set the text property directly from my view controller.

---

PS `CellAppDelegate` is a bad name for a view controller - the custom is to end the class name with `ViewController` so it would be `CellAppViewController`. This naming scheme makes it very easy to come back to your code in a week or so and still understand what everything does :)

Comment: Thanks!, I had to think about it a little bit, but got it, and will probably lead to some more noob questions. And, yeah for learned the 'why' of immutable data objects before object oriented programming existed. The book is pretty good, but wow Xcode leaves a lot to be learned. Again, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Everything so far seems tells me that I should not call a 'CellData' method from my 'CellView' class.

This sounds like a misunderstanding. It is extremely common for something like `CellView` to be handed a single `CellData` by the controller. The view is free to query the model object it is responsible for displaying. This is not a violation of MVC. It should generally not *write* to the model object, nor should it talk to *other* model objects typically.